# Из файла csv в базу вставляется меньше строк чем, собственно, есть в файле

Tags: база-данных, mysql

```
 $table='tab';
 $del=mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE
 `".$table."`");  $fp = fopen
 ("base.csv","r");
 while ($data =
 fgetcsv ($fp,0,";")) {
     $num = count ($data);

     for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {

 if ($del=false){break; echo 111;}

 $result=mysql_query('insert into tab
 (id1,id2,a3,a35,a5,p2,p3,p4,6a6,hf3)
 values
 ("'.$data[$c].'","'.$data[$c+1].'","'.$data[$c+2].'","'.$data[$c+3].'","'.$data[$c+4].'","'.$data[$c+5].'","'.$data[$c+6].'","'.$data[$c+7].'","'.$data[$c+8].'","'.$data[$c+9].'")');
    $c=$c+9;}} fclose ($fp);
```

Из файла `csv` в базу вставляется меньше строк чем, собственно, есть в файле.
При импорте через `phpmyadmin` их 13000+ а при данном 10980. Подскажите, я что-то не так делаю, или может есть способы проще?

Comment: по таймауту не отваливается случайно?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще у вас очень неоптимальная работа с БД.

Давайте попробуем так, а потом посмотрим на результат

```
$table='tab';
$del=mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE `".$table."`");
if (!$fp = fopen("base.csv","rb")) die('Не могу открыть файл')
$query = 'insert into '.$table.' (id1,id2,a3,a35,a5,p2,p3,p4,6a6,hf3) VALUES ';
$n = 0;
while ($data = fgetcsv ($fp,0,";")) {
  if (count($data) < 9) continue;
  if ($n > 0) 
    $query .= ', ';
  $n++;
  $query .= '("'.$data[0].'", "'.$data[1].'", "'.$data[2].'", "'.$data[3].'", "'.$data[4].'", "'.$data[5].'", "'.$data[6].'", "'.$data[7].'", "'.$data[8].'", "'.$data[9].'")';
  }
fclose ($fp);
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo $result ? 'Добавлено записей: '.$n : 'Ошибка в запросе: '.mysql_error();
```

**UPD**

Это грустная ошибка, у вас отваливается соединение.
Если есть доступ к конфигам Mysql, надо установить переменную `max_allowed_packet` в бОльшее значение (советуют 64М) и `wait_timeout` (советуют 60 сек).
Также в php перед запросом поставить

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Ибо может быть такое: файл обрабатывается за 28 сек, запрос идет 10 сек, а на 30-й апач обрывает выполнение скрипта.

Comment: Ошибка в запросе: MySQL server has gone away

Comment: Обновил. Кстати, возможно, до переписывания запроса было то же самое из-за количества запросов.

ЗЫ: если перечисленное не сработает или нельзя менять настройки, остается 2 варианта: разбивать csv файл на 2 поменьше (до 8мб), либо менять хостера, чтобы можно было менять настройки. Я для себя в одном проекте выбрал первый.

Comment: Ошибка в запросе: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Коврик" (24181)", "+", "2.85", "2.78", "2.70", "2.63", "0", "Parity"), ("28", "8' at line 1



Вот что ответила бд

Comment: Может есть более простые способы запихать csv файл в базы?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поможет использование load data infile, есть мнение, что работает быстрее всего.